# How do I create different landing pages?

Tags: views, panels

I am newbie to Drupal and I have deadline to make a website. So, I apologize if this question sounds silly to you..

I wanted to create a website that has one front page and 8 different landing pages. I have created front page. But I am not sure what is the best practice to create 8 different designed landing pages that are going to be use for the entire website.

For example:

- "About" page uses 2 column layout.
- "Contact Us" page uses 3 column layout.
- "News" page has flexible layout and so on.
  Also, News page has two image boxes with contents.

So, how do I create image box for one of my landing page?

So, can any one please guide me how do I create different landing pages?
I know there are several methods like, using panels, views and mini-panels we can create different landing pages. But, can any one suggest me good video tutorial and documentation for that?

Many Many Thanks!!

Comment: this question appears to be off-topic as it only requests tutorials and other online resources. Please see the help center for guidance in asking appropriate questions. a simple web search should yield hundreds of tutorials for what you want.

Comment: Seems like you already know the answer as you say you know of things like panels & views. As for finding teaching resources try google with keywords like "drupal", "panels", "tutorial", etc.

Comment: Simplest way is that create separate content type of different pages and correspondingly template files for it.
page--[content-type-machinename].tpl.php with your required layout

Answer (score 0):

You have to check [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) link for theming of different different page.